# Select and Insert across dblink

Tags: oracle, insert, dblink

I am having a bit of trouble with a select into insert across a dblink in oracle 10.  I am using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO LOCAL.TABLE_1 ( COL1, COL2) 
SELECT  COL1, COL2
FROM REMOTE.TABLE1@dblink s
WHERE COL1 IN ( SELECT COL1 FROM WORKING_TABLE)
```

When I run the statement the following is what gets run against the remote server on the DB Link:

```
SELECT /*+ OPAQUE_TRANSFORM */ "COL1", "COL2"
FROM "REMOTE"."TABLE1" "S"
```

If I run the select only and do not do the insert into the following is run:

```
SELECT /*+ */ "A1"."COL1"
     , "A1"."COL2"
  FROM "REMOTE"."TABLE1" "A1"
 WHERE "A1"."COL1" =
   ANY ( SELECT "A2"."COL1"
       FROM "LOCAL"."TABLE1"@! "A2")
```

The issue is in the insert case the enitre table is being pulled across the dblink and then limited localy which takes a fair bit of time given the table size.  Is there any reason adding the insert would change the behavior in this manner?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the driving_site hint. There is a good explanation here:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_dblink_performance.htm

Comment: I had tried adding the following hint to the initial query before posting but got the same results.

/*+DRIVING_SITE(s)*/

That would be hinting to drive on the dblink side correct?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to DML, oracle chooses to ignore any driving_site hint and executes the statement at the target site. So I doubt if you would be able to change that (even using WITH approach described above). A possible workaround is you can create a synonym for LOCAL.TABLE1 on the remote database and use the same in your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging the WITH clause could optimize your retrieval of your working set:

```
WITH remote_rows AS
     (SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(s)*/COL1, COL2
      FROM REMOTE.TABLE1@dblink s
      WHERE COL1 IN ( SELECT COL1 FROM WORKING_TABLE)) 
INSERT INTO LOCAL.TABLE_1 ( COL1, COL2)
SELECT  COL1, COL2
FROM remote_rows
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885154/oracle-sql-insert-into-with-with-clause#5885845) shows that your syntax here is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle will ignore the driving_site hint for insert statements, as DML is always executed locally. The way to do this is to create a cursor with the driving site hint, and then loop through the cursor with a bulkcollect/forall and insert into the target local table.

Answer (score 1):

How big is WORKING_TABLE ?
If it is small enough, you could try selecting from work_table into a collection, and then passing the elements of that collect as elements in an IN list.

```
declare
  TYPE t_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
  v_coll t_type;
begin
  dbms_application_info.set_module('TEST','TEST');
  --
  select distinct object_type 
  bulk collect into v_coll
  from user_objects;
  --
  IF v_coll.count > 20 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'You need '||v_coll.count||' elements in the IN list');
  ELSE
    v_coll.extend(20);
  END IF;
  insert into abc (object_type, object_name)
  select object_type, object_name
  from user_objects@tmfprd
  where object_type in 
            (v_coll(1), v_coll(2), v_coll(3), v_coll(4), v_coll(5), 
            v_coll(6), v_coll(7), v_coll(8), v_coll(9), v_coll(10),
            v_coll(11), v_coll(12), v_coll(13), v_coll(14), v_coll(15), 
            v_coll(16), v_coll(17), v_coll(18), v_coll(19), v_coll(20)
             );
  --
  dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
end;
/
```

Comment: That was my initial approach but there may be more than 1000 elements in the working table.  I think I will have to break the processing up by groups of 1000 to stay withing the where in limits.

Comment: Are you able to create a global temporary table on the remote side of the link ? You could insert into that from the work table, then the join would all be on the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into zith cardinality hint seems to work in 11.2

```
 INSERT /*+ append */  
        INTO MIG_CGD30_TEST       
                SELECT  /*+ cardinality(ZFD 400000) cardinality(CGD 60000000)*/ 
            TRIM (CGD.NUMCPT) AS NUMCPT, TRIM (ZFD.NUMBDC_NEW) AS NUMBDC
              FROM CGD30@DBL_MIG_THALER CGD,
                   ZFD10@DBL_MIG_THALER ZFD,
                   EVD01_ADS_DR3W2  EVD
```